# In TCP receive, opencv imdecode function returns zero from second turn in a while loop

Tags: c++, image, sockets, opencv, tcp

I try to display an image stream using a series of images that are transmitted via TCP communication.
In a sender side, multiple jpg image files are encoded as binaries using 'imencode' and transmitted serially.
In a receiver side, the received data is decoded and saved in a cv::Mat variable using 'imdecode' in a while loop.

The first received data is correctly decoded and saved in the cv::Mat variable but the second received data is not correctly decoded.
The 'imdecode' function, at this time, returns zero and all data is NULL.

How can I decode the binary data continuously in a while loop

Below is a part of my code

```
while (1) {
        cv::Mat img_rcv;
        std::vector<char> buffer;
        char recvbuf[FULL_BUFLEN];
        size_t len = sizeof(recvbuf);
        char *p = recvbuf;
        dataReceived = 0;

       /////////* receiving data *////////    
        while (len > 0 && (dataReceived = recv(ConnectSocket, p, len, 0)) > 0) {
            p += dataReceived;
            len = len - (size_t)dataReceived;
            if (len > 0 || dataReceived < 0) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        buffer.assign(recvbuf, recvbuf + sizeof(recvbuf));
        img_rcv = cv::imdecode(buffer, 1);

        // Display the resulting frame
        cv::imshow("received Image", img_rcv);
        ...

    }
```

'img_rcv' in a first loop is correctly generated so I can see the image using cv::imshow but the 'img_rcv' returns zero from the second loop.
I checked the 'recvbuf' is updated in the second loop.

Comment: How will your code know how many bytes are in each image?

Comment: I currently assign the buffer size with enough size. I have no idea how the receiver side code know the size of received data. Should the code know the size of the received data to resolve the problem? Is there any way to check the received data size?

Comment: That is exactly the issue. TCP sockets are not message-oriented, I mean you might send 1,000 bytes and the receiver might get 800 on the first read, then 196, then the last 4 bytes along with 200 of the next transmission from the sender, so you need to tell the other end how many bytes are coming. Most times, people put a 4-byte header on in network byte order so the client knows how much to read.

Comment: Here's a similar thing in Python... https://stackoverflow.com/a/61099429/2836621

Comment: you are right.
the problem is that the size of each frame must be exactly defined when decode the binary.
by referencing the python script, I communicate each frame with data head with frame size), and it works.

Thank Mark, I appreciate it.

Comment: Excellent - well done! you can write up and share your solution for all to use and then accept your own answer and grab the points if you wish. Good luck with your project.