# My python program freezes when I use 'recv()' with my client socket, how could I fix it?

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter, freeze

I'm trying to make a mail app, using socket, tkinter, etc. When I launch the program, it freezes after the loading screen. It doesn't show any error, just freezes. I debugged it, and found out where the 'error' was. I've tried using `setblocking()` or `settimeout()`, etc, but nothing worked. Maybe tkinter is the problem? Here are the most important parts of my client script, and server script

**CLIENT**

```
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

[...]

def after():
    client_socket.connect((IP, PORT))

    while True:
        msg = client_socket.recv(HEADER) # It freezes here (I found out it was here by debugging)

        try:
            msg = msg.decode(FORMAT)
        except Exception:
            msg = pickle.loads(msg)

        if msg:
            pass

def load_win():
    loading_bar.pack_forget()
    loading_title.pack_forget()
    loading_frame.pack_forget()

    main_label.pack()

    log_in_button.pack(pady=30)
    sign_in_button.pack()

    main_frame.pack(expand=YES)

    win.geometry('720x480')
    win.minsize(720, 480)
    win.config(bg='#3D3D3D')
    win.after(0, after)

def load_bar():
    loading_bar['value'] += loading_bar['length'] // 100

def load():
    total_nbr = 0
    for x in range(100):
        randint = random.randint(1000, 5000)
        total_nbr += randint
        loading_bar.after(randint, load_bar)

    win.after(total_nbr//100, load_win)

[...]

win.after(0, load)
win.mainloop()
```

**SERVER**

```
[...]

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

server_socket.bind((IP, PORT))
server_socket.listen()

[...]

while True:
    client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()

    [...]

    while True:
        msg = None

        try:
            msg = client_socket.recv(HEADER)
        except Exception:
            break

        try:
            msg = msg.decode(FORMAT)
        except Exception:
            msg = pickle.loads(msg)

        if msg == 'get_clients':
            client_socket.send(pickle.dumps(clients))
```

Comment: It freezes as `recv()` is a blocking call that will wait for some data to be received. You can set `conn.setblocking(0)` on the connected socket

Comment: Where is `HEADER` defined please?

Comment: You will confuse yourself if you refer to data received on a TCP socket as `msg` because  TCP is **stream-based**, not **message-based**. That means, if you send 1024 byes, you might receive 3 bytes in the first `recv()` followed by 7 in the next `recv()` followed by 1014 in the last `recv()`. There is no concept of a *"message"*. Have a look here for a very simple framing protocol... https://stackoverflow.com/a/62874813/2836621

Comment: According to your incomplete code the first thing both the server and client do is call `recv()`. Obviously they can't both receive first, someone has to do a `send()` first.