# Python TCP Server receives single TCP packet split into multiple packets

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I'm having some trouble identifying the cause of some packet splitting issues on a Python-based TCP server I am hosting.

After my client has connected to the server, it sends a string to the server, followed by `/n`.

A Wireshark preview of a packet can be seen below:
[image]

In this case, you can see the payload is *"as the extra special british baby potatoes/n"*

My TCP Server has the following receiving code:

```py
    def listenToClient(self, client, address):
        size = 1024
        while True:
            try:
                # Receive data from the client
                data = client.recv(size)
                print('CLIENT Data Received', client)
                print(datetime.now())
                print("Raw data received: ", data.hex())
                Data: as the extra
            except ConnectionAbortedError:
                print(datetime.now())
                print('CLIENT Disconnected:', client)
                client.close()
                return False
```

When receiving the above packet, it prints the following:

```
CLIENT Data Received <socket.socket fd=428, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('192.168.0.16', 12345), raddr=('192.168.0.14', 47234)>
2020-11-14 22:48:20.087507
Raw data received:  617320746865206578747261
Data: as the extra

CLIENT Data Received <socket.socket fd=428, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('192.168.0.16', 12345), raddr=('192.168.0.14', 47234)>
2020-11-14 22:48:20.092495
Raw data received:  207370656369616c2062726974697368206261627920706f7461
Data:  special british baby pota

CLIENT Data Received <socket.socket fd=428, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('192.168.0.16', 12345), raddr=('192.168.0.14', 47234)>
Raw data received:  746f65730a0a
2020-11-14 22:48:20.117488
Data: toes
```

Somehow, this single TCP packet has been split into 3 smaller packets.

Do you know how this may have happened?

Comment: Please see my comment here... https://stackoverflow.com/q/64790051/2836621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP is not a message based protocol but a byte stream. A single `send` does not mean that everything will be sent inside a single TCP packet. Similarly it cannot be counted on that a single `recv` will match a single `send`.

If you want message semantics you need to add these on top of the byte stream. Typically this is done with an explicit length indicator, a special separator or by having only a single message, i.e. close of connection will end the message. And then you need to call `recv` multiple times until you got the full message.

Comment: Thanks for this prompt answer. In this case, my "special separator" is the `\n` that I append at the end of each sentence. Is there a way to make recv block and keep concatenating the received stream until it comes across this `\n`?

I don't want to close the connection as for this purpose I needed a long-lived TCP connection :)

Comment: @OscarVanL: `recv` does not have the capability to read only until a specific character occurs. You need to implement this yourself. See for example [python socket readline without socket.makefile()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023885/python-socket-readline-without-socket-makefile) for some ideas on how to do it.

Comment: Thank you, this looks perfect. I will try that :)

Comment: I got it working by adapting this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57164667/6008271 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with the explanation of [Steffen Ullrich](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64839581/8006854) here is how you can structure your code to receive the whole message:

```
def listenToClient(self, client, address):
        size = 1024
        while True:
            try:
                # Receive data from the client
                data = ''
                while True:
                     r = client.recv(size)
                     if not r:
                         break
                     data += r
                print('CLIENT Data Received', client)
                print(datetime.now())
                print("Raw data received: ", data.hex())
                Data: as the extra
            except ConnectionAbortedError:
                print(datetime.now())
                print('CLIENT Disconnected:', client)
                client.close()
                return False
```

Comment: There's no guarantee the byte stream won't be split in the middle of a UTF-8 multibyte character, so you shouldn't decode it until you determine you have a complete message.  This code also assumes you keep receiving until the socket is closed, so could only receive one message.

Comment: @MarkTolonen you are absolutely right about the decoding part in my code. On the other hand about the second part of your comment, the question spoke of **a single TCP packet so a single message** unless I am mistaken

Comment: It mentioned sending a message followed by a \n, not necessarily closing the socket afterward.  It really needs a buffering layer that populates the buffer from the stream until a newline is seen, then returns the part of the buffer up to and including the newline.  Anything remaining in the buffer after that would be part of the next message.