# send and receive binary files properly using sockets c++

Tags: c++, sockets

hello stackflow users,

so i want to send and receive my binary file using sockets in c++ and here is how i send it from server program

```
send(Connections[conindex], reinterpret_cast<char*>(rawData), sizeof(rawData), NULL);
```

and here is how my client program receives it

```
char raw[647680];
recv(Connection, raw, sizeof(raw), NULL);
```

is there any proper way than this? i want so that i don't have to hard code the size every time.
or any other alternatives etc

Comment: First of all make sure you open the file in binary mode on both sides. Secondly *always* check what `send` and `recv` returns. Thirdly, never use string functions (like `strlen`) to handle the binary data. Fourthly, if you use TCP remember that it's a *streaming* protocol with no packet boundaries and that a single call to `recv` might receive *less* than was passed in a single call to `send`, so you always need to call `recv` in a loop.

Comment: And lastly, most internal buffers on the sockets and into the kernel, are usually not big enough to contain a whole large file. Use smaller buffers in your application, read the file and send chunks piece by piece, and as mentioned use a loop to receive and write the data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62874813/2836621

Comment: alright ill try it, thanks!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Why and how should we check for the return values of send and recv?

Comment: @KinoDerToten To detect errors, or end of connection. And you check when you do the calls. This is taught and showed in any decent book or tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rather general way to achieve this (in both C and C++) is something like this:

```
if (FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb"))
{
    size_t readBytes;
    char buffer[4096];
    while ((readBytes = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fp) > 0)
    {
        if (send(Connections[conindex], buffer, readBytes, 0) != readBytes)
        {
            handleErrors();
            break;
        }
    }
    close(Connections[conindex]);
}
```

And on the client side:

```
if (FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "wb"))
{
    size_t readBytes;
    char buffer[4096];
    while ((readBytes = recv(socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) > 0)
    {
        if (fwrite(buffer, 1, readBytes, fp) != readBytes)
        {
            handleErrors();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatives to this rather FTP-esque connection style includes sending the size of the file first, so the client will know when to stop listening instead of waiting for the disconnect.

Please note that this code is untested and merely meant to illustrate the concept.

Comment: Why use `fopen` and related functions in a C++ program?

Comment: Also be careful when using `size_t` here. The `size_t` type is an *unsigned* integer, but `send` and `recv` both returns *signed* integers. If, for example, `recv` fails and returns `-1`, then the comparison `(readBytes = recv(...)) > 0` will not work as expected.