# Sometimes Receiving shifted data with TCP

Tags: python, tcp, plc

I'm receiving packages where the content has its start not at the beggining of the buffer but at byte 2 or 3 of the buffer. That just happens sometimes. That means the received data are all shifted then.

I set the buffer size to 4096 bytes. I'm using the recv method from the Python sockets and am receving data from a Siemens PLC (if that's a possible source of issues).

Am I missing something out or has the error to be somewhere else than in my program?

Comment: TCP is a byte stream, not a message protocol. You can't assume that each call to `recv()` will exactly match a call to `send()`. Messages can be split up or merged.

Comment: If I set my buffer size to the exact size of the expected data would that help? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: What do you mean by the buffer starts at byte 2 or 3? What's in bytes 0 and 1? I'm assuming it's the last 2 bytes of the previous message.

Comment: The size of the buffer doesn't matter. It's just a maximum to read, but `recv()` can return earlier.

Comment: Have a read here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/62874813/2836621

Comment: The content of the buffer (or what the buffer should be) starts some bytes behind the start of the buffer.

Comment: I'm using TCP not as a message service. I'm just receiving single packets. Every packet has all data I need. But sometimes the beginning of the information is not at the beggining of the buffer. Does that mean the packet is already sent with this offset (that's also a possibility)?

Comment: It's just a stream, no message boundaries, no offsets. If you send 100 bytes, you might receive 8 bytes on the first read, then 90 on the next read, then 2 on the last read.

Comment: But that just explains when one message is sent with two packets. But what I'm having is that there are leading zeros. Does that mean. That these leading zeros are from the previous message?

Comment: Try sending a fixed number of bytes repeatedly and then read how many bytes you receive and print that number.

Comment: If your protocol truly needs to be packetized because it has no "framing" mechanism built-in, look at UDP instead of TCP with some kind of acknowledgement/checking feedback response.  UDP is connectionless, but it can provide framing, error detection/correction/retry like a serial port state machine protocol.  You also get to control over "timeout" durations (that's both a benefit and a curse).