# Python TCP server to communicate with ESP32

Tags: python, arduino, esp32, python-sockets, arduino-c++

I have a Python server running with this code:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('192.168.1.11', 5000))
s.listen(0)

while True:
    client, addr = s.accept()

    while True:
        content = client.recv(32)
        if len(content) == 0:
            break
        else:
            print(content)

    client.send(bytes('{\"accel\",\"gyro\",\"time\":1}', "utf-8"))
    print("Closing connection")
    client.close()
```

I want my ESP32 to communicate bidirectionally with the server.

This is the Arduino code:

```cpp
#include <WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "#########";
const char* password =  "######";
 
const uint16_t port = 5000;
const char * host = "192.168.1.11";
 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
 
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("...");
  }
 
  Serial.print("WiFi connected with IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}
 
void loop() {
  WiFiClient client;
 
  if (!client.connect(host, port)) {
    Serial.println("Connection to host failed");
    delay(1000);
    return;
  }
 
  Serial.println("Connected to server successful!");
 
  client.print("Hello from ESP32!");

  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.write(c);
  }

    char c = client.read();
  
    Serial.println("Disconnecting...");
    client.stop();
 
    delay(10000);
}
```

What I have done so far is, I have managed to send data from ESP32 to the server. But I have been unable to send commands from the server to ESP32.

I want to send the JSON from the server to the ESP32. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have a read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62874813/2836621 and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61099429/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am sorry to disturb you but I have a little problem understanding the articles here. Is my python server side sending code (client.send) is correct ?                     Is my Arduino client side receiving code (client.read) correct ?. If not could you please explain.Thanks