# Send img from pi using python sockets to display in real time using cv2 on windows

Tags: python, opencv, sockets, raspberry-pi, byte

I'm trying to send images from my pi to windows so I can use yolo on windows then send code back to my pi to control my robot.

I can't display the pictures sent by the pi on my pc in real time because the bytes are different every time and it messes up opencv. (opens half photo)

How would my code on windows know how many bytes are going to be in the photo being sent from the pi? Or is there another way to go about this?

Pi code:

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray 
from picamera import PiCamera 
import socket
import time
import cv2

listensocket = socket.socket() #Creates an instance of socket
Port = 8000 #Port to host server on
maxConnections = 999
IP = socket.gethostname() #IP address of local machine

listensocket.bind(('',Port))

# Starts server
listensocket.listen(maxConnections)
print("Server started at " + IP + " on port " + str(Port))

# Accepts the incoming connection
(clientsocket, address) = listensocket.accept()
print("New connection made!")

# Initialize the camera
camera = PiCamera()
 
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 20
 
raw_capture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))
 
time.sleep(0.1)

# Capture frames continuously from the camera
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(raw_capture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
     

    image = frame.array
     
    #cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
     
    # Wait for keyPress for 1 millisecond
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    
    cv2.imwrite("image.jpg", image)
    
    file = open('image.jpg', 'rb')
    
    file_data = file.read(56000)
    clientsocket.send(file_data)
    print("Data has been transmitted successfully")

    raw_capture.truncate(0)
    time.sleep(0.050)
     
    if key == ord("q"):
        camera.close()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
    
camera.close()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Windows code:

```
import socket
#import time
import cv2
#import sys


s = socket.socket()

hostname = 'raspi' #Server IP/Hostname
port = 8000 #Server Port

s.connect((hostname, port)) #Connects to server

file = open('image.jpg', 'wb')
file_data = s.recv(2048)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('image.jpg')

while file_data:
    # Save recent image from server
    file.write(file_data)
    file_data = s.recv(56000)
    print("File has been received successfully.")

    # Display image as video
    ret, img = cap.read()

    # Show image
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(50)
    if key == 27:
        break

file.close()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Have a read here for an idea about a simple *"framing protocol"* that tells the receiver how many bytes to read because TCP is not message-oriented - it is a continuous stream https://stackoverflow.com/a/61099429/2836621

Answer (score 0):

I don't have pi to test it with the exact setup but I did a similar project a while ago. My approach to this problem is either using a null-terminated header that will tell the client how many bytes the image will be. Alternatively, you can use a constant size header you decide before hands. For example first 4 bytes will tell the client how many bytes to be received. Here is a sample code snippet for the first solution I described:

sender:

```
import socket
import cv2 as cv

# read a test image
img = cv.imread('panda.jpg')
# encode it to jpg format, you can do this without redundant file openings
retval, buf = cv.imencode(".JPEG", img)
# get number of bytes
number_of_bytes = len(buf)
# create a null terminated string
header = "" + str(number_of_bytes) + "\0"
# encode it to utf-8 byte format
raw_header = bytes(header, "utf-8")
# create server socket
sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('localhost', 8000))
sock.listen()
conn, addr = sock.accept()
# send header first, reciever will use it to recieve image
conn.send(raw_header)
# send the rest of image
conn.send(buf)
```

reciever:

```
import socket

# create client socket
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 8000))

# recieve bytes until null termination
raw_header = []
recv_byte = sock.recv(1)

while recv_byte != b"\0":
    raw_header.append(recv_byte)
    recv_byte = sock.recv(1)

# decode header
header = str(b''.join(raw_header), "utf-8")
# recieve the amount of bytes foretold by header
recv_img = sock.recv(int(header))
# save image to file or you can use cv2.imendecode to turn it back to numpy.ndarray (cv2 image format)
with open("traveller_panda.jpg", 'wb+') as im_file:
    im_file.write(recv_img)


# transform back from jpg to numpy array
image_decoded = np.frombuffer(recv_img, dtype=np.uint8)
image_decoded = cv.imdecode(image_decoded, cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
# display image
cv.imshow("recieved", image_decoded)
cv.waitKey()
```

Comment: TCP isn't message-based, so `send(thousands_of_bytes)` and `recv(thousands_of_bytes)` can fail to send/recv the amount requested.  Check the return value of `send` or use `sendall`.  For `recv`, check the return value, buffer data and loop until you get the amount expected.

Comment: I've tried to add cv2.VideoCapture to the code and I keep getting `rror: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'`

Comment: I didn't check your video logic since you asked about transmissions. Since you have the frames in memory, you don't need to use `VideoCapture()`. Just use `cv2.imshow()` on the decoded frames. I'm adding a snippet to the above answer to show how to use `cv2.imshow()`. Just do that in your loop. Don't write and read from a file. It's slow and redundant.

Comment: Photo looks good on pi using `.array` but I still receive part of the photo. .. `for frame in camera.capture_continuous(raw_capture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    
    img = frame.array
    cv.imshow('img', img)
    retval, buf = cv.imencode(".JPEG", img)
    number_of_bytes = len(buf)
    header = "" + str(number_of_bytes) + "\0"
    raw_header = bytes(header, "utf-8")
    conn.send(raw_header)
    conn.send(buf)
    # Wait for keyPress for 1 millisecond
    key = cv.waitKey(50) & 0xFF
    # Clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
    raw_capture.truncate(0)`